# How to input ampersand(&), asterisk(*) and other characters in android 2.1 emulator?

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a new account in android 2.1 emulator. When I'm entering my password, I found it's impossible to input some symbols, such as #,$,&,*, except @. For example, while I press shift+7, only 7 is shown in the password textview.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Entering these special characters into the emulator works correctly for me (Linux, US International keyboard layout). Which platform are you using? Have you tried the emulator's on-screen keyboard?

Comment: I'm using Windows XP and Eclipse 3.42。 I've already tried on-screen keyboard. But I cannot input these characters. :(

Comment: As you mentioned that @ works: You know that you need to click "Alt" before any of the alternative symbols (!,#,$,&,...)?

Comment: @tg: i've already click 'ALT' key, but nothing different happens. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried toggling the input method from alpha to numeric/symbol?

Comment: thank you Vamsi, I've already toggled to numberic/symbol, but there is no #, & symbols. I cannot input these symbols with my PC keyboards, either.

Comment: why do want to enter using PC keyboard? u do have a emulator keyboard or you can use softkeyboard when you try to focus on the edit-text box. between i was able to enter symbols through my pc-keyboard. please do check the keyboard locale of the pc

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. On your phone, you have to ensure that the settings for the keyboard/locale match your computer settings. Find the Settings icon and go from there.

Comment: i haven't an android phone, I'm using  an emulator. I'll try your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't enter special characters with the pop-up soft keyboard, the PC's hardware keyboard, or the gray keyboard to the right of the emulator window on 2.3.3 emulator (API10).

However, when I tried on the 4.0.3 (API15) emulator, the PC's hardware keyboard entered symbols without a problem.  The gray keyboard to the right of the window would just repeat keys if I held them down to get to the symbols.  The soft keyboard wasn't available on my configuration and I didn't spend any time trying to configure it to do so.